# How many triangles are there with whole number side?

Tags: geometry, triangles, integers

If  $a=29$, and $b=21$, how many triangles are there such that side $c$ is a whole number?
My approach: Tried using certain equations to establish relationship between sides to maybe point to right answer, but to no avail.

Comment: Considering natural numbers, the side $c$ must be within $1$ and $49$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe $c$ can be $1$?

Answer (score 3):

Since by the triangle inequality $$29+21>c$$ and $$c+21>29,$$ we obtain:
$$9\leq c\leq49.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Exactly what I wrote on my comment eight minutes ago ...

Comment: We were probably all typing at the same time.

Comment: @Michael Hoppe See please better your comment. I think they are not exactly the same.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the concept underlying this is called the triangle inequality; gives the OP (or future readers) something to look up in case he wonders where this result came from.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that the original inequality is actually $8 < c < 50$ but $9$ and $49$ are the most "extreme" integers in that range (since $8,50$ are not in it).

Answer (score 1):

No equations needed.  These two sides must be connected.  How long or short could the third side be?

The longest is clearly when $a$ and $b$ are in a line without overlap.  Their ends will be $29 + 21 = 50$ apart.

The shortest is again when they are in line but overlap.  The unjoined ends will be $29 - 21 = 8$ apart.

Are these degenerate extremes triangles?  You decide.

However, all of the lengths between these extremes are certainly triangles.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of geometry:

Draw $a=\overline{BC}=29;$

Draw a circle about $C$ with radius $r=21$.

$2$  Intersection  points of circle with $BC$ :

1) $D_1$ where $\overline{BD_1}= 8$;

2) $D_2$ where $\overline{BD_2}=8 +2\cdot 21= 50$.

The locus of $A$ are the points on this circle.

Hence $8< c <50$, or $9 \le c \le 49$.

How many integers c with above constraints?